# How to round an integer UP to the nearest 15 in PHP

Tags: php, html, logic, rounding

I have the INTEGER(255) variable `$duration` stored with a value taken from the user. I need to round this UP to the nearest 15. I have searched all over but haven't been able to find a solution.

How may I go about doing this?

For example:

- 10 becomes 15
- 16 becomes 30
- 130 becomes 135

Also, how can I add `$duration` to a TIME variable `$time` to output the time after that duration?

For example, from `080000`:

- If `$duration` is 15, `$time` becomes 081500
- If `$duration` is 30, `$time` becomes 083000
- If `$duration` is 135, `$time` becomes 101500

Thank you!

Comment: You can try this logic for duration  ((round($duration/15)*15) + 15).

Comment: You can use ceil or floor too instead of round function. You will need to do little try and error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the simple division and addition with casting (will return the whole value without the fraction) operator as follows:

```
$val = 130;//or any value
$roundedVal = ((int)($val/15) + 1) * 15;
```

about the second question:

```
$time='080000';
$valHours = (int)($val/60);
$valMin = (int)($val % 60);
$time = $time + ($valHours * 10000) + ($valMin * 100);
$time = strlen($time) == 8? $time : '0' . $time;
```

the last row is meant or fixing the leading zero, since it's not a conventional time format.
I haven't took into consideration the seconds.